# Observable.combineLatest is not a function

Tags: angular, routerlink

I have a **Home** page, somewhere in it the user clicks on **Contact me** to be redirected to the **Contact** page:

**home.component.html**

```
<div>
  <a routerLink="/contact" [queryParams]="sendOBj">Contact me</a>
</div>
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { FollowersService } from '../followers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  myfollowers: any[]; 
  sendOBj: {id: any, name: any};

  constructor(private followers: FollowersService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myfollowers = this.followers.getFollowers();   
    this.sendOBj = {id: this.myfollowers[0].id, name: this.myfollowers[0].name };
  }

}
```

**contact.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    Observable.combineLatest([
      this.route.queryParamMap
    ])
      .subscribe(
        combined=>{
          let id = combined[1].get('id');
          console.log('id', id);
        }
      );

    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe();    
  }
}
```

By clicking on **Contact me** on **Home**, I get this error:

```
ContactComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.combineLatest is not a function
```

Please help me find out the problem.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Your imports are not valid for Angular v6.

Comment: I use version 5.

Answer (score 8):

In angular 6,

you just need:

```
import {combineLatest} from "rxjs/index";
```

and replace

```
Observable.combineLatest(...)
```

by

```
combineLastest(...)
```

Comment: I just upgraded to Angular 6. Now even **import {combineLatest} from "rxjs/index";**  gives error. I can use **import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/operators/combineLatest';** instead, but in this case I cannot subscribe to **combineLatest**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

I first upgraded to Angular 6, then modified **contact.component.ts** like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';    
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CombineLatestSubscriber } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs/operators/combineLatest';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.route.paramMap.subscribe();

      this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
        user=>{
          console.log('username: ', user.get('name'));
          console.log('user id', user.get('id'));
        }
      );        

  }
}
```